# How come I don't need an invoke for some form elements a non-GUI thread?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a `BackgroundWorker` that calls a function on a non-GUI thread. I've noticed that for some form elements I can get away with updating the GUI without doing the invoke. Others will still result in a runtime error because the program attempted to update the GUI in a non-threadsafe way.

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've probably stumbled upon some methods or properties that don't check context and throw an exception. That doesn't mean it is a good idea to do so. Infact, I would avoid it at any cost.

**Update:** 
Assuming WinForms here. 
If you think it is too cumbersome to invoke, use an extension method:

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
   public static void Do(this Control c, Action f)
   {
      if (c.InvokeRequired)
      {
         c.Invoke(f);
      }
      else
      {
         f();
      }
   }
}
```

Then, in DoWork of BackgroundWorker:

```
// Background work here
this.Do(() =>
{
   // This runs on UI thread
});
```

I find this a lot easier to use than BackgroundWorkers ReportProgress.

Comment: Is it costly to call this function for controls that end up not requiring an invoke?

Comment: As you can see in the code above, no, it is not costly. If Invoke is not required, the call will be made in the same thread. I wouldn't worry about it. If you're processing tens of thousands of items, don't report progress for each item, or redrawing will be slow. :)

Answer (score 2):

Not all gui elements and their methods are translated to WM_something.  There are methods that work directly not using message queue at all.  Therefore, they are safe to use from any thread.

Comment: Good point, but it is so easy to invoke, that I still think it is safer to not make any such assumptions.

Comment: I agree - so, to be on the safe side, Invoke *always*!